# Java mvn exec performance

Tags: java, performance, maven, exec, maven-plugin

Is there much performance difference when running a java application using the exec plugin vs running using the java command line?
e.g.

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="FixTradeTest"
```

vs

```
java FixTradeTest
```

Comment: I wouldn't assume there is a significant difference unless you have seen otherwise. I assume the startup time is slightly longer.

Answer (score 0):

The exec plugin runs programs inside the same JVM maven is running in. Assuming you use the same JVM flavor for both maven and your java command line, there shouldn't be a big different *if that's all you do*.

If you are running a build and finally run this java class, then you'll be starting the JVM once, vs once for maven, and once for your program. On the other hand, you risk having properties set on your JVM that affect the behavior of your program.

Check [this](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) out if you haven't yet (look for *Differences compared to plain command line*).

Comment: Another difference is it changes the behaviour of UncaughtExceptionHandler. This is a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since `mvn exec:java ...` would run in the same JVM as Maven, there wouldn't be much of a difference, except for the fact the running `java my.MyClass` would always be a tad quicker, as Maven will execute some operations before actually running the class.